# Refresh Firebase iOS SDK cache immediately

Tags: ios, swift, caching, firebase

Is there a way to manually and immediately refresh the Firebase cache, using the iOS SDK, to pull down the latest data (assuming you are online)? For example, if I made some changes to my data on Firebase, I want my app to reflect that immediately, but with persistence turned on, it usually takes a few restarts of the app.

I recently turned on persistence in my app like so:

```
Firebase.defaultConfig().persistenceEnabled = true
```

It worked great, but now my app doesn't refresh it's data very often even with an internet connection. I'm using the offline capabilities mentioned [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html).

Comment: "with persistence turned on, it usually takes a few restarts of the app" That shouldn't happen, unless you use `observeSingleEventOfType`. Since `observeSingleEventOfType` will fire immediately for the cached version, it'll never get the new version. The solution is to not use both `observeSingleEventOfType` and `persistenceEnabled = true`.

Comment: To ensure the cache gets updated automatically, call `[ref keepSynced: YES];`.  https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache

Comment: So according to your first comment, even `keepSynced` wouldn't work if I'm using `observeSingleEventOfType`?

Comment: This is now `FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true` as of Google's acquisition of Firebase, if i'm not mistaking.

Comment: And now in *Swift 3*, it is actually `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` :)

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen What happens in the following instance? Step 1. viewController is pushed, observeSingleEventOfType is called in viewDidLoad.  Step 2. viewController is popped off the stack, Step 3. viewController is pushed again, and it follows same  process as in step 1. Does it mean that in step 3, `observeSingleEventOfType` downloads only the cached data and any updates made in Database between Step 2 and Step 3 will not be downloaded?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelenI read your answer and removed the SingleEvent Listener from the code. Now used the following, but still not refreshing cache.
<pre>weak var weakSelf = self
            valueRef = dbRef?.observe(.value) { (snapShotData) in
                
                if singleValueObserver
                {
                    weakSelf?.dbRef?.removeObserver(withHandle: weakSelf?.valueRef ?? 0)
                }
                weakSelf?.dataFetched(snapShotData)
            }</pre>

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem with persistence and here are two options solving it:

1) Keep using `observeSingleEventOfType` but setting `ref.keepSynced(true)`. This won't listen to changes happening in your data but it refreshes data once this code is executed. I've chosen this option for my FAQ section which just needs to update once when the screen is opened (viewDidLoad).

2) Use `observeEventOfType`. This will always keep your data in sync and will execute again as soon as your data changes.

Comment: this works fine on my iPhone 7+, but not on my iPhone 5s, but running iOS 10... what may be the reason for not working on iPhone 5s? Not working means that the "immediate" response is missing but the server call is always made

Comment: Thanks a lot Raphael