# observeSingleEvent(of:with:) fetching old data

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Background:

I have an app where new users complete a sign-up form (consisting of a username, email, and a password) to register for an account. When the new user submits the form, the app checks its Firebase Database to see if the username has already been taken. The problem here is that `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` is not getting the newest data. When I update the data directly from the Firebase console, the changes are not reflected back in the returned results of `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)`. Even between app restarts, the new data changes are not returned.

The only thing I've seen on the issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935547/refresh-firebase-ios-sdk-cache-immediatly). A user says not to have persistence enabled when using `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)`. But, I have persistence disabled. Also, I set the `keepSynced()` on the `FIRDatabase` instance to false (and I've tried true as well). No luck with either setting.

Here's an example of what I am trying:

```
let usersDatabaseReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
usersDatabaseReference.keepSynced(false)

// Query the database to see if the username is available 
// The user with the username "mark" was removed from the database via the Firebase console
let username = "mark" // This user used to exist in the database (and was previously added through the app).  
usersDatabaseReference.child(username).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in ... } )
```

The above code block should return the newest data (one where the user "mark" should not exist).

I am wondering if anyone else ran into this problem, or if anyone has possible solutions.

Note: Developing using iOS 10.1 and swift 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my problem had nothing to do with caching or fetching old results. Some of my code logic depended on checking the `value` of the `snapshot` parameter that was passed back in the completion handler for `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)`. I wrongly assumed that I could check for a `null` database value by comparing it with `nil`; this led to a misinterpretation of results.

The best way to actually check for a `null` database fetch is by calling the `exists()` method on a `FIRDataSnapshot` instance. `exists()` returns `true` if the `snapshot` contains a non-`null` value.

Answer (score 1):

the `observeSingleEvent(of:with:)` return the value only one time

try this :

```
refHandle = postRef.observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
  let postDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] ?? [:]
  // ...
})
```

this will add a listener on database event [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Comment: Adding a listener while the app is running makes sense. But what about when the app is terminated? When the user starts up the app again, there wouldn't be a listener to pick up the changes right? I am under the assumption that the cache is related to time as opposed to app-restarts/data-changes.

Comment: it will restart again

Comment: Still doesn't work for me. What's even weirder is that I stopped messing around with the app over an hour ago. It *still* says that the username has been taken.

Comment: @hvasam Are you sure you are on the *latest* Firebase client framework version?

Comment: I am using the official Firebase SDK found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/libraries/. My project is less than a month old.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you refactor your JSON data model using the *username* as key. Doing this, you should get an error when trying to create a duplicate user in the database.

Comment: I've already done that. Currently, there is a users path in the database. And to identify the users, I've been using their usernames.